# Multiple accordions using jQuery - closing issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a page, which has a number of accordions on it. I want by clicking on any of the accordions (they all currently have only one item in them each) to close all the rest of them, so that my graph stays intact.

Please see the page at:
http://php.york.ac.uk/fs/hlth531/squelettes/js-graph/js-graph2.html

My code currently is:

```
$(function(){
var xxx  = '#pg_prog_com, #dis_com, #msc_pub, #msc_pub_int, #msc_hser, #msc_hsci, #msc_cancer, #msc_haem, #msc_cbt, #gard_prog, #lib_com, #pg_res, #dep_head, #vle_sup, #marketing, #marketing, #fin_dev, #phd_prog, #phd_prog, #phd_adm, #adm_asi, #adm_tutor';
$( xxx ).accordion({
    autoHeight: false,
    collapsible: true,
    active: false
    }); 
});
```

Thanks in advance,

Nadia

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind a 'accordionchange' event, and toggle the other accordions.

```
$('.ui-accordion').bind('accordionchange', function(event, ui) {
    ui.newHeader // jQuery object, activated header
    ui.oldHeader // jQuery object, previous header
    ui.newContent // jQuery object, activated content
    ui.oldContent // jQuery object, previous content
});
```

The normal use of accordions, are use a single one with different section, that toggle themself automatically.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. It lead me to the solution (see below).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full solution for the script section (obviously the HTML page contains the actual accordions)

```
<script>

$(function() {
    var xxx  = '#pg_prog_com, #dis_com, #msc_pub, #msc_pub_int, #msc_hser, #msc_hsci, #msc_cancer, #msc_haem, #msc_cbt, #gard_prog, #lib_com, #pg_res, #dep_head, #vle_sup, #marketing, #marketing, #fin_dev, #phd_prog, #phd_prog, #phd_adm, #adm_asi, #adm_tutor';

    function collapseAll(id) {
        //alert("calling collapseAll");
        $( xxx ).not('#'+id)
            .filter(":has(.ui-state-active)")
            .accordion("activate", -1);
        $(".ui-accordion-header").blur();
    }

    $( xxx ).accordion(
        autoHeight: false,
        collapsible: true,
        active: false
    }); 

    $( xxx ).accordion("option", "icons", {
        'header': 'ui-icon-carat-1-s', 'headerSelected': 'ui-icon-carat-1-n'
    });

    $(xxx).bind('accordionchangestart', function(event, ui) {
        collapseAll(this.id);    
    });
});
</script>
```